# Express.JS Body Parser Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I've been trying to parse a body request and I always get undefined. I've included both `app.use(express.json());` and `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` in my code but it still returns undefined. This is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const jokes = require("./jokes.json");

app.post("/api/jokes", (req, res) => {
    const newJoke = {
        question: req.body.question,
        answer: req.body.answer
    };

    console.log(req.body.question); // Logs Undefined
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running and listening on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your code should just work, are you sure you are sending the body variables? can you give us the piece of code that send the data to the server?

Comment: @pablohenrique I used postman to create a post request that has the data in the body

Comment: Try doing a console.log on the req.body itself to see what kind of data is being sent

Comment: Why do you post a code without middleware but describe that you actually use it? Can you add the request to the question?